# STarT Questionnaire Meaning

Tags: pain, terminology, back, lumbago-low-back-pain

When referring to the STarT questionnaire. Why is "STarT" capitalised like that?

I can't seem to find a definition of it as an acronym.

The STarT questionnaire, also know as the STarT Back questionnaire, is used to sub-group patients into low/medium/high risk of chronicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STarT Back stands for Screening and Targeted
Treatment for Back pain.

Comment: How about a reference to support that? It is a rather short answer...